# Mask first set of characters in a textbox using ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

On a webform, I have a field for social security number. I want to only display the first 3 numbers and asterik (or mask) the remaining numbers. Is there an easy way to do using OOB .Net functionality? It is client side functionality because the asteriks would appear on the 4th number through the last number. Wondering if there is a jquery library anyone knows about or the client side code is easy enough.

Comment: Let me ask you this: **WHY** do you need someone's social security number? Also, considering the quality of this question, I would be doubtful towards you using SSL.

Comment: SSN was just an example.  The actual question is if while a user is typing the set of numbers (4th through the last number) are masked.  This would have to be something on the client side.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think we have a inbuilt functionality to achieve this.

You can just replace the remaining characters with *** in the server side

Please check the following link 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/t0kbytzc(v=vs.94).aspx

Answer (score -1):

You should do that in server side like this

```
  Dim S As String = "1234567"
  TextBox1.Text = S.Substring(0, 3) & New String("*", S.Length - 3)
```

Comment: **ONE** This question regards JavaScript. **TWO** This doesn't preserve what would originally be in the text box if you replace `S` with `TextBox1.Text`.